# How to get independent increment of equation numbers

Tags: equations, numbering, amsart

I want the increment of the equation counter to be independent of other increments.

**The setup I have :**

Theorem 1.1

Equation (1.2)

Corollary 1.3

Equation (1.4)

Lemma 1.5

Lemma 1.6

Proposition 1.7

Equation (1.8)

**What I really want :**

Theorem 1.1

Equation (1.1)

Corollary 1.2

Equation (1.2)

Lemma 1.3

Lemma 1.4

Proposition 1.5

Equation (1.3)

**In the preamble I have :**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[equation]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[equation]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[equation]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{principle}[equation]{Principle}
\newtheorem{claim}[equation]{Claim}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[equation]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[equation]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[equation]{Example}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change

```
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
```

to

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{theorem}{section}
```

Or, more succinctly,

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % Thanks, @Bernard!
```

Second, change

```
\newtheorem{proposition}[equation]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[equation]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[equation]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{principle}[equation]{Principle}
\newtheorem{claim}[equation]{Claim}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[equation]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[equation]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[equation]{Example}
```

to

```
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{principle}[theorem]{Principle}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
```

Comment: What I got by making the changes : Definition 1, Theorem 2, Equation (1.1), Corollary 3, Equation (1.2)

But I want is : Definition 1.1, Theorem 1.2, Equation (1.1), Corollary 1.3, Equation (1.2)

Comment: @pkxop - I've added `\numberwithin{theorem}{section}` after `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}`.

Comment: You may slightly condense the code with `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`.